# TypeError: Response is not a constructor in Expo SDK 33

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, expo

After upgrading to Expo SDK 33 from 32, there are issues with running tests in jest. When mocking a get return value, Jest complains about Response not being a constructor.

```js
const mockGet = jest.fn();
mockGet.mockReturnValue(new Response(
    JSON.stringify({
        data: true
        }),
    { status: 200 }
    ));
```

Here is a snippet of the current `package.json` of the relevant packages.

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@types/enzyme": "3.9.1",
    "@types/expo": "^32.0.13",
    "@types/jest": "23.3.10",
    "@types/react": "^16.5.0",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.57.20",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "enzyme": "3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.12.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "3.3.5",
    "eslint": "5.11.0",
    "jest": "24.8.0",
    "jest-cli": "24.8.0",
    "jest-expo": "^33.0.0",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "raf": "3.3.2",
    "ts-jest": "^24.0.2",
    "tslint": "5.12.0",
    "typescript": "3.5.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "jest": "node node_modules/jest-expo/bin/jest.js --runInBand",
    "lint": "tslint src/**/*.ts",
    "test": "npm run jest && tslint src/**/*.tsx && eslint .",
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "json"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "raf/polyfill",
      "<rootDir>/test-setup.js"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^33.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
  }
```

Before the upgrade from 32 to 33, these tests using the Response object were successfully working. Now after the upgrade the test suite raises the TypeError.

The only modules that changed versions are `jest-expo` (32.0.0 -> ^33.0.0), `ts-jest` (23.10.5 -> ^24.0.2), `typescript` (3.4.3 -> 3.5.2) and finally `expo` (^32.0.0 -> ^33.0.0). The `react-native` module was also updated from the Expo react-native archive sdk-32 to sdk-33.

I have tried different versions of modules in an attempt to see where the definition of Response changed. For example, I downgraded `jest-expo` from v33 to v32 while `expo` was v33. This wasn't helpful, as it caused the test-suite to fail completely, as shown below.

```
● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'expo-react-native-adapter' from 'setup.js'

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/@jest/core/node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:230:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-expo/src/setup.js:203:6)
```

Any help on how to stop the TypeError from showing up during the tests would be greatly appreciated. It may also be helpful to note that TypeScript does not detect this type error in intellij.

Comment: refer link https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20460#issuecomment-411858190

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I found was with how the mock inside the jest-expo module was defined. I was able to get around this issue by creating a patch (using [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) module). The patch is below. You can add this to "patches/jest-expo+33.X.X.patch" in the root and add "postinstall": "patch-package" post-install hook to the package.json file.

```
diff --git a/node_modules/jest-expo/src/preset/setup.js b/node_modules/jest-expo/src/preset/setup.js
index 1d791d4..bb3d9a0 100644
--- a/node_modules/jest-expo/src/preset/setup.js
+++ b/node_modules/jest-expo/src/preset/setup.js
@@ -5,7 +5,6 @@
 'use strict';

 // whatwg-fetch@3 expects "self" to be globally defined
-global.self = global;

 const { Response, Request, Headers, fetch } = require('whatwg-fetch');
 global.Response = Response;
@@ -148,18 +147,16 @@ mockNativeModules.NativeUnimoduleProxy.modulesConstants = {
 };

 jest.mock('expo-file-system', () => ({
-  FileSystem: {
-    downloadAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ md5: 'md5', uri: 'uri' })),
-    getInfoAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ exists: true, md5: 'md5', uri: 'uri' })),
-    readAsStringAsync: jest.fn(),
-    writeAsStringAsync: jest.fn(),
-    deleteAsync: jest.fn(),
-    moveAsync: jest.fn(),
-    copyAsync: jest.fn(),
-    makeDirectoryAsync: jest.fn(),
-    readDirectoryAsync: jest.fn(),
-    createDownloadResumable: jest.fn(),
-  },
+  downloadAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ md5: 'md5', uri: 'uri' })),
+  getInfoAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ exists: true, md5: 'md5', uri: 'uri' })),
+  readAsStringAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
+  writeAsStringAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
+  deleteAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
+  moveAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
+  copyAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
+  makeDirectoryAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
+  readDirectoryAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
+  createDownloadResumable: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
 }));

 jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Image/AssetRegistry', () => ({
```